# LESS CSS @import for javascript

Tags: javascript, import

Do you know if there's some kind of tool like LESS CSS but for Javascript that allows you to import for example "plugin-1.js"; in my .js file. I'm working with a sublime text 2 build for LESS (which references dotless.exe), so maybe if you've tried something like that it'll be awesome if you can share it with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in `HTML` JavaScript in the web you can organize your imports with libraries like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or to simply include another script tag above the one you're already using in your HTML.

```
<script src="plugin-1.js" type='text/javascript'> </script>
```

Otherwise, if you're using node.js this is done with the `require()` directive as such

```
var otherModuleToRequire = require("plugin-1.js");
```

After which it will be available in the file.

It is worth mentioning that while this are similar to `@import` in functionality they behave differently by doing the importing in *run time* instead of bundling all the files into one which is what @import does.

If you really care about bundling the files (for example in production under load) you can use minifiers and optimizers like [the closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) or [the require.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) if you chose to use require.js.